# Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy? Please help!

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I’m going through a tough time financially and decided to find someone who can give me money. Within 3 days of talking, this man paid me. He's asking me to send money to his daughter through Cash App and I’ve seen a lot of stories of people being scammed in that way. He does not have my banking information but he made me send a picture of my ID to make sure I wasn’t scamming. I did, but crossed out all personal info, leaving just my face and name. Should I trust him?

Comment: #1 Why in the world would some random guy on the intenet just **give** you money without **getting** something in return?  #2 If he can send money to **you** then he can send money to his daughter. #3 **Heck no** you shouldn't trust him?

Comment: @RonJohn The answer is prostitution ("Sugar daddy" is just a euphemism) However, this does sound like a scam. Either proposition sounds dubious and to be avoided.

Comment: @JohnFx the moderators frown on calling people prostitutes.

Comment: @JohnFx - I think you missed RonJohn's point. OP is expecting money just for talking online without meeting in person. And RonJohn asked why a random guy would pay money just to talk. ;)

Comment: @TTT: I think you missed JohnFx's point, which was a simple definition.  In standard American English usage (before this particular scam arose), a "sugar daddy" is a man (usually older) who supports a (usually younger) woman financially in exchange for sex.

Comment: @jamesqf - of course I know that. But that would be getting something in return. RonJohn asked why a guy would give money *without* getting something in return. The answer to RonJohn's question is definitely not prostitution. A possible answer would be something along the lines of "maybe the guy is super lonely and is really kind and likes to give money away to strangers he's never met".

Comment: @JohnFx and jamesqf - maybe it would be helpful to know that (AFAIK) all the sugar daddy questions on this site are from women who have never met their sugar daddy in person.

Comment: While "sugar daddy" used to mean a person who supports you financially in exchange for sex, in terms of common usage I'm now beginning to think it means "person who is trying to scam you by pretending to give you money".

Comment: @TTT And I wonder why. There are far too many very similar questions asked within a tiny time window now for me to take them seriously any more. I’m starting to believe somebody is having a laugh at this site.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very common scam. The money he sent you is fraudulent and the bank will ultimately reverse it. However, if you send money to his "daughter," then that is real money you will lose.

A sugar daddy would never ask you to send money to his daughter. Why can't he do it himself? There are similar scams for craiglist sales, jobs, etc. Never send money to someone you don't know, nor should you attempt to "return" money that you are sent by someone you are not close to.

If you think something is fraudulent, just let the bank or payment processor fraud department know about your concern. Don't try and act on it yourself.

Comment: You might want to clarify for future readers the difference between *returning* a payment and getting the bank to *reverse* the payment.

Comment: I don't encourage people to try and reverse payments made into their accounts. You can let your bank or payment processor know you *think* the payment is fraudulent and the fraud department will do what they think is best. If the scammer somehow sends legit money into your account, keep it.